# Converting map to string in Go

Tags: json, go, nomad

I am trying to find the best way to convert `map[string]string` to type string.

I tried converting to JSON with [marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) to keep the format and then converting back to a string, but this was not successful.

More specifically, I am trying to convert a map containing keys and values to a string to accommodate *[Environment Variables](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/template.html#environment-variables)* and *[structs.go](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/blob/master/nomad/structs/structs.go#L3647)*.

For example, the final string should be like

```
LOG_LEVEL="x"
API_KEY="y"
```

The map

```
m := map[string]string{
        "LOG_LEVEL": "x",
        "API_KEY": "y",
    }
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah can you explain how should be the final string?

Comment: You're not showing what you tried, and your description is very vague. From the looks of it, the values are not all strings (eg: `true` is not the same as the string `"true"`).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need some key=value pair on each line representing one map entry, and you need quotes around the values:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func createKeyValuePairs(m map[string]string) string {
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    for key, value := range m {
        fmt.Fprintf(b, "%s=\"%s\"\n", key, value)
    }
    return b.String()
}

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG",
        "API_KEY":   "12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc",
    }
    println(createKeyValuePairs(m))

}
```

Here is [a working example on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eRW0NEvBfEr).

Answer (score 21):

You can use `fmt.Sprint` to convert the map to string:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d",
    }

    log.Println("Map: " + fmt.Sprint(m))
}
```

Or `fmt.Sprintf`:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d",
    }

    log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Map: %v", m))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this very simple and pragmatic:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string {
        "LOG_LEVEL": "x",
        "API_KEY":   "y",
    }

    var s string
    for key, val := range m {

        // Convert each key/value pair in m to a string
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%s=\"%s\"", key, val)

        // Do whatever you want to do with the string;
        // in this example I just print out each of them.
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

You can see this in action in [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sOu_x_5uUAG).

Comment: config files can be very long thats why i used the bytes.buffer

Comment: @ShabanNaasso: I agree; it depends on the use case.

Answer (score 4):

This could work:

```
// Marshal the map into a JSON string.
mJson, err := json.Marshal(m)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

jsonStr := string(mJson)
fmt.Println("The JSON data is: ")
fmt.Println(jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could convert map to single line using sf.MapToStr function from `github.com/wissance/stringFormatter v1.0.1` (https://github.com/Wissance/stringFormatter):

```golang
// ...
import (
    sf "github.com/wissance/stringFormatter"
)
// ...
func MyFunc() {
    options := map[string]interface{}{
        "connectTimeout": 1000,
        "useSsl":         true,
        "login":          "sa",
        "password":       "sa",
    }

    str := sf.MapToString(&options, sf.KeyValueWithSemicolonSepFormat, ", ")
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jsonString, err := json.Marshal(datas) 
fmt.Println(err)
```